# I recently installed cygwin but when i run any command in it, it says "-bash: git: command not found"

Tags: git, github, git-svn

I recently got a brand new computer with decent configuration.
Today I have installed cygwin, and when I open it and run any command like "**git status**" by visiting my htdocs directory **c:/xampp/htdocs/testapp**

Then, always it returns "-bash: git: command not found".

After that I installed the Git Bash for Windows from http://git-scm.com/, where I can run the Git commands and it works fine, but not the cygwin again.

Is there any clue, what should be done to get cygwin working?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running Git through Cygwin from Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15692890/running-git-through-cygwin-from-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Old thread but if you cd to your home dir then cd to cygdrive/c/xampp/htdocs/testapp that will work for you.

Cheers,