# Git Clone under Cygwin hangs

Tags: git, cygwin

This is something of a mystery. I just installed Cygwin on my Windows machine (Windows 8). The very first thing I tried was git clone (I was cloning a private repository using ssh, rather than anything on github). It announced cloning into blah-blah-blah, and then just froze. I waited several minutes, and nothing. I looked at the directory, and there was a directory created with the .git subdirectory, but nothing else. It never got around to asking for my password.

I am able to use git from a Windows command prompt, and the git shell that I downloaded from the Git website works. So there's no problem with my git connection. It's just git under Cygwin.

You might ask why I'm bothering, if I can use git outside of Cygwin. It's just because I'm trying to debug some git hook scripts that I wrote, and I want them to be usable by someone using git under Cygwin. But I can't even get to the point where the git hooks are called.

Comment: It's not true that git is completely broken under Cygwin. If I clone a repository outside of Cygwin, I can do git checkout, git status, git branch. But git clone and git commit just hang. So maybe that's a clue of some sort.

Comment: Okay, so the reason that git commit was hanging was simple: I had not specified a default editor for commit messages. You would think that that would cause error message, rather than causing git to freeze, but...

That still leaves the git clone mystery. There might be something similar going on with settings.

Comment: Aha! Yet another clue: If I try to clone a git project that doesn't require a password, that works. So somehow, the problem is with the code that creates the prompt for a password

Comment: same problem here, thanks for you investigation. is there a chance you are still online sometimes and have found anything more about this issue?

Comment: Hi, Dominik. Unfortunately, I didn't get any further on this. I stopped using Cywin for git, and instead have been using the git bash shell. So this is unresolved.

Comment: Yeah. I have changed to git console as well. Probably we sholud report a Bug, don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

> I didn't get any further on this. I stopped using Cywin for git, and instead have been using the git bash shell

I usually make sure to use a [separate PATH when using cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15702140/6309).
If I use Git, I make sure to reference a [simplified PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51199066/6309).

In both instance, you need to make sure `$HOME` reference the right folder, as credentials can be stored there by default (`~/.ssh` for your SSH keys for instance)