# ssh-add creates Error connecting to agent: Connection timed out (Windows 10)

Tags: git, github, ssh

I am trying to add my ssh to git. I have generated it, there are 2 files in ~/.ssh
In a terminal (MINGW64) I type:

```
$ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
```

It responds:

```
Agent pid 3480
```

Then I type

```
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

It responds (after like 15 secs):

```
Error connecting to agent: Connection timed out
```

The whole code (with no ssh-agent.exe processes run):

```
MNXALbl4@DESKTOP-GTSHV44 MINGW64 /c/NodeWebServer (master)
$ ls -al ~/.ssh
total 36
drwxr-xr-x 1 MNXALbl4 197609    0 июл  5 02:05 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 MNXALbl4 197609    0 июл  5 02:08 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 MNXALbl4 197609 3243 июл  5 02:05 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 MNXALbl4 197609  741 июл  5 02:05 id_rsa.pub

MNXALbl4@DESKTOP-GTSHV44 MINGW64 /c/NodeWebServer (master)
$ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
Agent pid 12824

MNXALbl4@DESKTOP-GTSHV44 MINGW64 /c/NodeWebServer (master)
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Error connecting to agent: Connection timed out
```

Any ideas? I tried all solutions I could find.

Comment: Does your private key have a passphrase?

Comment: no, it was generated through the standard " ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "myEmail@yandex.ru" " command, and then had nothing done with it.

Comment: Then you don't need ssh-agent. At all.

Comment: Thank you, thou the course I am currently taking (following all of the steps), explicitly showed all of the above steps (including the agent launch, with the same key creation path) working for the instructor, without any errors on his side (it was on mac OS thou)

Comment: OK, I suppose adding a passphrase-less key to an agent should work (even if it is not useful). What git version are you using on your Windows?

Comment: git version 2.16.1.windows.1

Comment: And would the issue persist with Git 2.18? (https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases)

Comment: I just re-installed git with 2.18 version, and still the same mistake persists

Comment: Does your ssh key works for authenticating to the remote repo? `ssh -T git@<remoteServer>`

Comment: It does, the command (i used @github.com) returned the correct data.

Comment: Then you are good to go: skip the agent step and crack on.

Comment: I'll put an answer later today.

Answer (score 1):

If `eval $(ssh-agent -s)` (without quotes) does not yield better result ([as seen here](https://superuser.com/a/901616/141)), don't forget that the SSH agent is needed only for private SSH keys protected with a passphrase.

For testing, try the same command in a git bash launched after [setting a simplified `PATH` for Git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45779657/6309):

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set GH=C:\path\to\git
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%

set PATH=%PATH%;/path/to/ThreadScope/bin
```

This is not the case here, and `ssh -T git@github.com` returns the expected "Welcome" message, which validates your authentication.

So you can ignore that `ssh-agent` step, and simply proceed with the rest of your work: `git clone git@github.com:anAccount/aRepo`, ...