# How to specify git path in Cygwin terminal?

Tags: git, ssh, cygwin

I installed Cygwin and TortoiseGit. And I created ssh-key by `ssh-key-gen -t rsa` and registered public key to my GitHub page. When in `gitbash` terminal, it worked, however, `Cygwin` terminal failed.

```
// Cygwin
$ git pull
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I noticed they use different git. Then, how do I specify git path in Cygwin? My OS is Windows 10.

```
// Cygwin
$ where git
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
$ which git
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Git/cmd/git

// gitbash (MINGW64)
$ where git
C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\git.exe
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
$ which git
/mingw64/bin/git
```

Comment: with cygwin uses its git. it will make easier to manage the ssh-key created with cygwin ssh-key-gen

Answer (score 2):

The git path itself is not that important for ssh.

What matters is the `$HOME`, because git (any git) would search for the public/private ssh keys in `$HOME/.ssh`

Double-check your `echo $HOME` output in both scenario, and check the result of `ssh -Tv auser@aserver` (replace user and server by the beginning of the ssh URL seen when typing `git remote -v`)

Also, [Cygwin has its own Git package as I explain here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15702140/6309).
And [it needs a `.bash_profile` as a setting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46627454/6309).

Comment: `$HOME` set correctly and ssh authentication was success by `ssh -Tv`. I still think this git is not set correctly.

Comment: @jef can you set the environment variable `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` (`set` on `CMD`, `export` on bash) to `ssh -v`, and see in both case what happen on `git pull`? There should be a difference.

Comment: @jef And you did not mention you were using a passphrase-protected ssh private key (https://stackoverflow.com/q/46627127/6309)