# Github SSH access: Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git, github, git-remote

I've recently set up a git repository on Win10 via Cygwin and now I'm trying to make it track a remote repo on github.

The problem is, that after adding a remote like this:

```
 git remote add github-remote git@github.com:username/github-remote.git
```

I cannot access it in any possible way (pushing, fetching, displaying additinal info by 'show'). All I get is this:

> git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
>
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

Although I know this topic's been discussed a lot, none of the solutions I found actually helped. That's why I decided to post yet another question.

Here's what I did, step-by-step:

1) Generated the pub-priv keypair:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "mymail@ex.com"
```

Tried with both - a default and a custom directory for the id_rsa files. Same results.

2) Ran the ssh agent (or checked for it running, to be precise):

```
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
```

3) Added the key to the agent

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

4) Copied the id_rsa.pub to github

5) Checked if the connection's set properly

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

... with a promising result of

> You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell
>   access.

From what I learned this error may be due to git's address not being included in the /.ssh/known_hosts file. The thing is (as far as I know) that it is being inserted automatically e.g. with 'ssh -T' so I doubt it's the case, either. Although tried that as well:

```
ssh-keyscan -t rsa github.com | ssh-keygen -lf -
```

Another possible problem could be my private key's access being available too widely for the users, but I checked that, too.

With all that said I have no further idea how to fix this one, so I'd appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. It seems you've done all the normal ssh/git debugging steps. If you can `ssh git@github.com` you should be good. However, it's possible your `git` is not using the same ssh configuration as your `ssh` commands. How did you install Git and how did you install ssh? It's possible it's not communicating with your ssh-agent. Try running the `git` commands in the same shell where `ssh` works.

Comment: There should not be a space in the middle of `git@github.com: username/github-remote.git`

Comment: @Schwern As for git, I downloaded the .exe from https://git-scm.com/download/win. SSH on the other hand I had to install as a Cygwin's package, and it's Cygwin's mintty in which I run all of the commands, so I guess that's good.  Feel free to go into more detail if I misunderstood what you meant, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Thanks for pointing that out, although I added the space accidentally while posting. It's not in the actual address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *As for git, I downloaded the .exe from git-scm.com/download/win. SSH on the other hand I had to install as a Cygwin's package, and it's Cygwin's mintty in which I run all of the commands...*

Mixing Cygwin and [Git For Windows](https://gitforwindows.org/) is likely the problem. While I'm sure there's a way to make them work, it's simplest to stick to one or the other.

Git For Windows comes with its own "Git Bash" shell and, I believe, ssh. Use that.

Or, if you want to stick with Cygwin, [get Git from from Cygwin](http://www.celinio.net/techblog/?p=818) and use that.

[Running Git through Cygwin from Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15692890/running-git-through-cygwin-from-windows#15702140) might also be useful.

Comment: Turns out that was it. Installing git via Cygwin did the trick! Thanks a lot :)