# Setting up Git server on Windows with CopSSH, but got this error: does not appear to be a git repository

Tags: git, copssh

I follow the steps to set up the Git server here: https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/wiki/Setting-up-a-Git-server-on-Windows-using-Git-for-Windows-and-CopSSH , everything work correctly until the last step that I clone the repository from server.

At the middle of setting up, I encoundted some other errors, but are all solved. They are:

1. File `libiconv-2.dll` not found: copy the file `libiconv-2.dll` from `git/bin` to the `ICW/Bin`.
2. File `git-receive-pack.exe` not found: create **3 soft link** `git-receive-pack.exe`, `git-upload-pack.exe`, `git-upload-archive.exe` at `ICW/Bin`, the source files are `git/libexec/git-core/*`.

At the last step that clone repository from server, I got this error:

I got this error:

```
$ git clone git@127.0.0.1:/cygdrive/d/GitRepo/Test.git
Cloning into 'Test'...
fatal: '/cygdrive/d/GitRepo/Test.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Any one can help? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the tutorial is intended to work in a [git bash session](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16772497/6309) from [msysgit](http://msysgit.github.io/) (as [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9011152/6309)).
Not in a cygwin session (and that explains your dll issue or softlink creations).

The last step is:

```
git clone {username}@{servername}:{repodriveletter}:/{repopath}
```

Which suggests a command like:

```
git clone git@127.0.0.1:/D/GitRepo/Test.git
# or, as the OP found out:
git clone git@127.0.0.1:d:/GitRepo/Test.git
```

I would recommend [not using cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15702140/6309) (as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8371676/6309)), and use msysgit instead.

Comment: `git clone git@127.0.0.1:/D/GitRepo/Test.git` still not working. But this is working: `git clone git@127.0.0.1:d:/GitRepo/Test.git`. Thanks!

Comment: @AlbertZhang Excellent. I have added this syntax in the answer for more visibility. Did you still used the git from cygwin?

Comment: I'm kind of lost in the "sessions". Does a "session" means a shell? I remember that the configuration of CopSSH is done in the Unix Shell from CopSSH (_Start Menu > Copssh > 03. Start a Unix BASH Shell_). And create the repository, testing clone is done in the git bash (_Start Menu > Git > Git Bash_).

Comment: @AlbertZhang the Git Bash shell is a Unix Shell, which defines a `$HOME` for you (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3455231/6309). So you can configure your CopSSH in *that* (git-bash) session.