# which msysgit version to download?

Tags: git, msysgit

I gave up on [cygwin's version of Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724471/git-slows-down-emacs-to-death-how-to-fix-this), and now I would like install [msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list?can=1&q=&colspec=Filename%20Summary%20Uploaded%20ReleaseDate%20Size%20DownloadCount) instead.

The problem is... they are all **[preview](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list?can=1&q=&colspec=Filename%20Summary%20Uploaded%20ReleaseDate%20Size%20DownloadCount)** versions.

I need Git for production. Is there a `stable` release out there?

To further complicate matters, I have been working (checking in and out) with git version `1.7.5.1` on cygwin... Does this change the answer?

Comment: Note that msysgit uses [5-year old](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/issues/31) (or [even older) versions of many base system files](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/issues/75) like ssh.exe, grep.exe etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I also find it frustrating that mysisgit only lists preview versions.  However i've been running them for almost 2 years now and have seen no ill effects.  I would just download the latest preview version and go with that.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I just noticed the 64-bit **pre-alpha** version, so if I'm guessing correctly, msysgit redefined "release/stable" as "preview" and "alpha" as "pre-alpha"?

Comment: @WinWin I've never used the pre-alpha.  Even on 64 bit windows I stick with the 32 bit preview version.

Comment: I had no intention of downloading the 64-bit version. I was just wondering about the terminology. There must be some rational behind this.

Comment: I have also been using the latest available for the last 3 years with no issues.

Comment: @WinWin whenever i read **alpha** i mentally substitute **scary preview**.  I don't know what the name rationale is but alpha will probably always scare me :)

Comment: @Adam Dymitruk Thanks +1 for the extra reassurance. Accepting.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for the 'preview' is in the msysGit repo in the file [HowToRelease.txt](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/master/share/WinGit/HowToRelease.txt).

I think that msysGit is getting close to meeting the criteria suggested of:

```
A setup executable is named as follows

 - it starts with Git;
 - followed by the official git version if the release is closely
   related to a specific version of official git;
 - followed by
    * preview<date>, for snapshot builds.
    * winrc#, if we reach a certain quality level and plan to release
      a stable version.  If no bugs are found, this can be upgraded
      to a stable release.  We use winrc instead of simply rc to avoid
      confusion with official release candidates.  The prefix "win"
      clearly indicates that the tag is about the Windows release.
```

Given the general quality and stability of msysGit it may be that there is an alternative that better reflects that feeling on the msysGit list msysgit@googlegroups.com